Click on link item in nextjs trigger full page reload instead navigate to subpage
I have a very strange error. When I click on link in my nextjs app, instead of navigate to that page, there is a full reload of the entire page. I have to click again to make it works. Do you know the possible reason? Below is my code if it might help
============================================================
'use client';

import { useCurrentUser } from '@/api/user/hooks';
import { ColorfulButton } from '@/app/(marketing)/colorful-button';
import { Chat } from '@/components/chat';
import { HeaderFeaturesSheet } from '@/components/header-features-sheet';
import { HeaderProfilePopover } from '@/components/header-profile-popover';
import { HeaderProfileSheet } from '@/components/header-profile-sheet';
import { Notifications } from '@/components/notifications';
import { RegisterDialog } from '@/components/register-dialog';
import { ModeToggle } from '@/components/theme-toggle';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/navigation-menu';
import { TextGradient } from '@/components/ui/text-gradient';
import {
  studentHeaderAppLinks,
  teacherHeaderAppLinks,
} from '@/config/header-app-links';
import { useIsDesktop } from '@/hooks/use-is-desktop';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import { FiArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { GiDatabase, GiWhiteBook } from 'react-icons/gi';
import { RoughNotation } from 'react-rough-notation';

export function HeaderApp() {
  const { data: user } = useCurrentUser();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isDesktop = useIsDesktop();

  return (
    <header
      className='scrolled:mt-0 fixed z-40 mt-[40px] w-full border-b bg-header'
      style={{
        boxShadow: 'var(--header-shadow)',
      }}
    >
      <div className='container flex h-20 items-center justify-between px-4 py-8 md:px-6'>
       

          <div className='hidden gap-6 md:flex'>
            <NavigationMenu>
              <NavigationMenuList>
                <NavigationMenuItem>
                  <NavigationMenuTrigger>
                    <RoughNotation
                      type='underline'
                      show={'/homeworks' === pathname}
                      color='var(--secondary-gradient-start)'
                    >
                      {'/app/homeworks' === pathname ? (
                        <TextGradient
                          color='secondary'
                          className='font-semibold'
                        >
                          Zadania
                        </TextGradient>
                      ) : (
                        'Zadania'
                      )}
                    </RoughNotation>
                  </NavigationMenuTrigger>
                  <NavigationMenuContent className='flex gap-1.5 p-2'>
                    {[
                      {
                        href: '/homeworks',
                        title: 'Baza zadań',
                        description:
                          'Szukaj zadań spełniająch określone kryteria.',
                        icon: GiDatabase,
                      },
                      {
                        href: '/homeworks-books',
                        title: 'Zadania z podręczników',
                        description:
                          'Rozwiązania zadań z popularnych podręczników oraz zbiorów zadań.',
                        icon: GiWhiteBook,
                      },
                    ].map((item) => (
                      <Link
                        key={item.href}
                        href={item.href}
                        legacyBehavior
                        passHref
                        className='flex-1'
                      >
                        <NavigationMenuLink className='w-[250px] rounded-sm bg-background p-2 hover:bg-muted'>
                          <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-1.5'>
                            <item.icon className='h-12 w-12 fill-gold-10' />
                            <div>
                              <p className='font-bold'>{item.title}</p>
                              <span className='text-sm text-muted-foreground'>
                                {item.description}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </NavigationMenuLink>
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </NavigationMenuContent>
                </NavigationMenuItem>
              </NavigationMenuList>
            </NavigationMenu>
            {(user?.role === 'TEACHER'
              ? teacherHeaderAppLinks
              : studentHeaderAppLinks
            ).map((item) => (
              <Link
                key={item.href}
                href={item.href}
                className={cn(
                  'relative flex items-center text-lg font-medium text-foreground transition-colors hover:text-foreground/80 sm:text-sm'
                )}
              >
                <RoughNotation
                  type='underline'
                  show={item.href === pathname}
                  color='var(--secondary-gradient-start)'
                >
                  {item.href === pathname ? (
                    <TextGradient color='secondary' className='font-semibold'>
                      {item.title}
                    </TextGradient>
                  ) : (
                    item.title
                  )}
                </RoughNotation>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='flex items-center gap-x-2'>
          <ModeToggle />
          {user ? (
            <>
              <Chat />
              <Notifications />
              {isDesktop && (
                <HeaderProfilePopover
                  links={
                    user.role === 'TEACHER'
                      ? teacherHeaderAppLinks
                      : studentHeaderAppLinks
                  }
                />
              )}

              {!isDesktop && <HeaderProfileSheet />}
            </>
          ) : (
            <div className='flex items-center gap-x-4'>
              <Link href='/login'>
                <Button
                  variant='ghost'
                  className='hover:bg-inherit hover:underline'
                >
                  Logowanie
                </Button>
              </Link>

              <RegisterDialog>
                <ColorfulButton>
                  Załóż konto{' '}
                  <FiArrowRight className='transition-transform group-hover:-rotate-45 group-active:-rotate-12' />
                </ColorfulButton>
              </RegisterDialog>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}



Can you show your code snippet?

added code to question
